# MediaElement.js + MP4-only fails on FF 3.6 for OS X

Tags: mediaelement.js

What I want:

To include a single MP4 video file in my website and have that file play through HTML5's  element for supported browsers (Safari, IE9, iOS, etc.)

For all other browsers, I'd like MediaElement.js to take that MP4 file, wrap it up in Flash and play it that way.

Basically, I don't want to host and encode both MP4 and VP8/WebM/Ogg. Now, MediaElement.js does this well on all browsers except FF 3.6 on OS X.

There, if I include a  tag with only an MP4 source, FF will not fall to a Flash player. Instead, it dims the video's poster frame and quits.

It's not my code: Firefox 3.6 exhibits the exact same behavior with the demo that is distributed with MediaElement.js itself. The MP4-only video fails. Including an Ogg source in the  tag solves the problem, obviously, but that's exactly what I don't want to do --- include 2 video files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, Firefox 3.6 on the Mac work great. However, it does not work on local files due to Flash security issues. Have you tried it on a live webserver?

Comment: Here's the page where you can allow flash to work locally on your machine. [Flash Settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html). I just tested it and it works for me.